# Is it common for election candidates to talk about spoiler candidates helping them?

Tags: united-states, election

[Trump: A vote for the Green Party helps me](http://thehill.com/blogs/ballot-box/presidential-races/289554-trump-a-vote-for-stein-would-be-good) reports that Trump has mentioned that people voting for the Greens' candidate will help him.

Is it common for a candidate to say publicly, before an election, that people voting for a certain candidate will help their own chances?

Comment: Whatever your opinion of Trump's politics, the man has never been accused of holding his thoughts close to the vest. So it's rather irrelevant whether it's common to other politicians, when discussing him :)